# Como adicionar valores de uma coluna de uma tabela já existente em uma nova tabela outra tabela?

Tags: postgresql

Tenho uma tabela `carga`, com a coluna `numeracao_carga`.
E uma outra tabela `produto`, com a coluna `numeracao_carga` sendo chave estrangeira da `numeracao_carga` da tabela `carga`.

Como faço pra adicionar os valores `numeracao_carga` da tabela `carga`, na coluna `numeracao_carga` da tabela `produto`?

Comment: Nos ajude a te ajudar, qual o código de criação das tabelas? Pode fornecer exemplos de dados dessas tabelas? Uma lida em [exemplo mínimo completo e verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-completo-e-verific%c3%a1vel) pode ajudar.

Answer (score -2):

Bom dia voce deve usar uma query de insert incial esperando uma resposta e depois fazer o insert em outra tabela.
Ex:

```
WITH carga_insert AS (
  INSERT INTO carga
    (numeracao_carga, campo2 , campo3 , campo4)
  VALUES
    (null, '25a', '00912', 'test 2')
  RETURNING numeracao_carga_insert)
INSERT INTO cproduto
  (id_produto , numeracao_carga)
SELECT null, numeracao_carga_insert
FROM carga_insert
```

Answer (score -2):

Bom dia.

Seria fazer um insert select puro mas como é uma chave primária vai dar erro.

```
insert into carga (select numeracao_carga from produto);
```

Neste caso poderia usar a cláusula on clonflict.
veja documentação e exemplos aqui: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html

```
INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING/UPDATE
```